# How to combine nested associative array and pluck?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

With

```
Model1::all()
  ->map()
  ->only(['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
```

I get

```
[
  { "c1": "v11", "c2": "v21a", "c3": "v31a" },
  { "c1": "v11", "c2": "v21b", "c3": "v31b" },
  { "c1": "v12", "c2": "v22a", "c3": "v32a" }
]
```

I would like to have

```
{
  "v11": {
    "v21a": "v31a",
    "v21b": "v31b",
  },
  "v12": {
    "v22a": "v32a",
  }
}
```

How do I do that? I tried different approaches but I can't make it...

---

With a lot of try and error I found it out. **Solution**:

```
Model1::all()
  ->map()
  ->only(['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
  ->groupBy('c1')
  ->map(fn($item) => $item->pluck('c3', 'c2'))
```

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried "groupBy(['c1', 'c2'])" and "pluck('c2, 'c3'), but I need a combination of this two. Does this help you to answer my question?